# my express page only loads once and fails the second time

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb

I have an express page that updates a doc in a mongoose database when it receives a post request from a jquery post request, and it does, but only once and when I enter another doc it fails. My mongoose collection has two docs in the collection with the location as Vancouver.

jquery page

```js
$("#sendover").click(function(){

  var settings = JSON.stringify({
   type : $("#type option:selected").text(),
   productname : $("#name").val(),
   collectionname : $("#groupings option:selected").text(),
   segment : $("#segment option:selected").text(),
   levels : $("#levels option:selected").text()
  });

  console.log(settings);

   $.ajax('/logic', {
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: settings
        }).done(function () {
            console.log('message saved successfully');
        }).fail(function (err) {
            console.log('failed to save message:');
         console.log(err);
            console.log(err.stack);
        }).always(function () {
        });
  
 });
```

node js

```js
router.post('/logic',function(req,res,next){
 
 var stock = mongoose.model("vault",{
  name:{type:String},
  location:{type:String},
  minspent:{type:Number},
      minlength:{type:Number},
  member:{type:Boolean}
 });

 if(req.body.type == 'collection'){
  //edit corresponding attribute of all the items in that collection
  console.log("it is collection");
 }else if(req.body.type == "item"){
  //edit the corresponding attribute of the item
  product = req.body.productname;
  section = req.body.segment;

  stock.findOne({name:product}, function(err,doc){
    if(err){console.log("failed to update doc");}
    doc.location = "The 6";
    doc.save();
  });
 }
 console.log("it went through");
 res.json({ ok: true });
  
});
```

the html that sent the post

```html
<form>
 <select id="type">
  <option value="" disabled selected>content type</option>
  <option value="collection">collection</option>
  <option value="item">item</option>
 </select><br>
 <input type="text" id="name"><br>
 <select id ="groupings">
  <option value = "collection1">Collection 1</option>
  <option value = "collection2">Collection 2</option>
  <option value = "collection3">Collection 3</option>
  <option value = "collection4">Collection 4</option>
 </select><br><br>
 <select id="segment">
  <option value="location">certain location</option>
  <option value="minamount">Only if they've spent min-amount</option>
  <option value="minlength">min-duration member</option>
  <option value="existence">Only if they are members</option>
 </select><br><br>
 <select id="levels">
  <option value="pictures">images</option>
  <option value="prices">prices</option>
  <option value="wholeitems">wholeitems</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" id="sendover">Set</input>
</form>
```

the first time around, it works and I get this console log

```
it went through
POST /vaultsetup 200 62.787 ms - 11
```

the second time around I get this

```
POST /vaultsetup 500 17.834 ms - 1933
```

and I know the jquery post goes through each time because of the developer tools console logs the settings string. Can someone explain why this code only runs once?

Comment: That's a 500 internal server error response code.  What do you see in your nodejs logs?

Comment: That's it up there, the last 2 lines of the console log. The rest are just 304 statuses

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error from Mongoose as you are trying to overwrite the `vault` model.

Every time you send a POST request to that endpoint you are trying to create the `vault` model. You're not allowed to do this. Try moving the definition outside of the POST method:

```
var stock = mongoose.model("vault",{
    name:{type:String},
    location:{type:String},
    minspent:{type:Number},
    minlength:{type:Number},
    member:{type:Boolean}
});

router.post('/logic',function(req,res,next){

    if (req.body.type == 'collection') {
        //edit corresponding attribute of all the items in that collection
        console.log("it is collection");
    } else if (req.body.type == "item") {
        //edit the corresponding attribute of the item
        product = req.body.productname;
        section = req.body.segment;

        stock.findOne({name:product}, function(err,doc) {
            if(err){console.log("failed to update doc");}
            doc.location = "The 6";
            doc.save();
        });
    }
    console.log("it went through");
    res.json({ ok: true });
});
```